# Assume role IAM Role from within an SSM command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

My use case is from lambda to issue a command to an ec2 that the instance profile role does not have access too. I used SSM to try and assume my target role but I get a very generic error that the configured profile does not exist. However I know the configured profile does exist and I am able to successfully assume the role locally after SSH'ing in.

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):

    ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
    response = ssm_client.send_command(
                InstanceIds=['i-xxxxxxxxx'],
                DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
                Parameters={'commands': ['aws sts assume-role 
--role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/myrole
--role-session-name "RoleSession1" 
--profile test> assume-role-output.txt' ]} )

    time.sleep(2)
    command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']

    
    output = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(
          CommandId=command_id,
          InstanceId='i-xxxxxxxxxx',
        )
 
    return output
```

This returns "StandardErrorContent": "\nThe config profile (test) could not be found\nfailed to run commands: exit status 255",

For anyone see's this do not use sts assume role from ssm,
rather use the profile as an argument aws s3 ls --profile test

Comment: The error is about `profile test` not any role. Do you have such a profile created?

Comment: Yes the profile exists and the command runs fine when executed from inside the ec2

Comment: Its not clear what you are doing. Where do you run the command? Not on the instance?

Comment: When I run the command on the instance it works. When I run the command from lambda it does not.

Comment: The SSM agent runs on EC2 instances as the root user, not ec2-user or ubuntu (for Ubuntu images). Your config profile was probably added as the ec2-user, hence it's not available to the root user. Either sudo to ec2-user or provide the config file to the root user in the appropriate location (probably `/root/.aws/`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [SSM Agent technical reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent-technical-details.html):

> On Linux and macOS [EC2 instances], SSM Agent runs as the root user. Therefore, the environment variables and credentials file that SSM Agent looks for in this process are those of the root user only (/root/.aws/credentials). SSM Agent doesn't look at the environment variables or credentials file of any other user accounts on the instance during the search for credentials.

Your AWS config file containing the `test` profile was probably added as the ec2-user, or ubuntu on Ubuntu, hence it's not available to the root user.

You could either `su ec2-user` to the ec2-user or provide the config file to the root user in the appropriate location (probably /root/.aws/).